# Using managed metadata in Current navigation in SP 2013

Tags: 2013

I am trying to use Managed metadata navigation as Current navigation/Side navigation Bar in a SharePoint intranet publishing site. I found one problem when I was configuring it:

If we have the terms in the term set defined as follows:

```
├─> Root1
│    ├─> L11
│    │   ├─> L21
│    │   │   └─> L31
│    │   └─> L22
│    ├─> L12
│    └─> L13
├─> Root2
└─> Root3
```

(Please consider the indents as children of parent terms).

So, there are 3 root terms and 4 levels of nesting in the terms. When I configured this for navigation it showed me only the 1st level by default i.e. Root1 -> L11, L12, L13 , Root2, Root3 in the navigation.
So, the navigation is not fully displayed. If I navigate to a lower level, it shows me one more level below it and does not show the parent i.e. on navigating to L12, to shows me L21 and L22, but does not show the child L31 and the parent Root1. I presumed it would show me the full hierarchy.

I did some probing around and figured that I could fix this by changing the master page.
I navigated to the html file of the master page and within the vertical navigation snippet I found "PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource" that had these properties:

StartFromCurrentNode(true)
ShowStartingNode(false)

I changed these values, that is, set 'StartFromCurrentNode' to false and 'ShowStartingNode' to true. I also set 'EnableViewState' to true which was false by default.
Still , this did not fix the navigation.

I am working on SharePoint 2013 RTM without the PU/CU updates from March, April or June.

Can anybody confirm this 'bug' of SharePoint 2013 RTM ? Is it fixed in the latest updates ?

Comment: Edited to make the term set flow a little easier

Comment: Any new findings? These values 'StartFromCurrentNode' and 'ShowStartingNode' seems to show no effect...